# How to check if scientific notation double or not C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, double, scientific-notation

I basically want to check if line is a valid scientific double or not.

So basically, if a line had a character like `a` or just a few characters like `help` or `0.a` then it would be considered as not a scientific double and rejected, however something like `1.234E+9` or `2.468E9` would be stored as it is an acceptable value

I have written some code to handle this however I need some help... differentiating between a scientific double and just some characters

```
char *temp;
int u=0;
int arrayLen = strlen(temp);
for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
  if(isalpha(temp[i]))
  {
    if((temp[i] == 'e') && (!isalpha(temp[i-1])))
    {
      break;
    }
    u++;
  }
}

if(u > 0)
{
   temp[0] = 0;
   break;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::stod` or its C equivalent (`strtod`).

Comment: Do you have the possibility to use regular expressions? It is a one-liner then.

Comment: @T.C. errr - or just that *cough* brilliant. Too easy. :-D

Comment: What about using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and using the appropriate [I/O manipulators?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip)

Comment: @T.C. How do I use strtod in my code?

Comment: If you get "1234.45E2text" do you want "1234.45E2" or "0"?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis I want "0". Basically, if it is just text like "a" or "text" I want it to be rejected

Comment: It's unlikely that the program has a bottleneck in data initialisation. So the the answer is to handle as doubles, then convert to int using a cast, with bounds checking if that is an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As T.C. suggest, use strtod.  But check the return pointer to see if it read all the content.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double convert_number( const char * num )
{
   char * endptr = 0;
   double retval;
   retval = strtod( num, &endptr );
   return ( !endptr || ( *endptr != '\0' ) ) ? 0 : retval;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int index;
    for( index = 0; index < argc; ++index )
        printf( "%30s --> %f\n", argv[index], convert_number( argv[index] ) );
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
./a.out 13.2425 99993.3131.1134  13111.34e313e2  1313e4 1 324.3 "2242e+3"
                       ./a.out --> 0.000000
                       13.2425 --> 13.242500
               99993.3131.1134 --> 0.000000
                13111.34e313e2 --> 0.000000
                        1313e4 --> 13130000.000000
                             1 --> 1.000000
                         324.3 --> 324.300000
                       2242e+3 --> 2242000.000000
```

--------------------ALTERNATIVE PER REQUEST ----------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int convert_number( const char * num, double * retval )
{
   char * endptr = 0;
   *retval = strtod( num, &endptr );
   return ( !endptr || ( *endptr != '\0' ) ) ? 0 : 1;
}


int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int index;
    double dvalue;
    for( index = 0; index < argc; ++index )
        if( convert_number( argv[index], &dvalue ) )
            printf( "%30s --> %f\n", argv[index], dvalue );
        else
            printf( "%30s --> Rejected\n", argv[index], dvalue );
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
./a.out 13.2425 99993.3131.1134  13111.34e313e2  1313e4 1 324.3 "2242e+3" 0.0
                       ./a.out --> Rejected
                       13.2425 --> 13.242500
               99993.3131.1134 --> Rejected
                13111.34e313e2 --> Rejected
                        1313e4 --> 13130000.000000
                             1 --> 1.000000
                         324.3 --> 324.300000
                       2242e+3 --> 2242000.000000
                           0.0 --> 0.000000
```

Newbie version:

```
int convert_number( const char * num, double * retval )
{
   char * endptr = 0; /* Prepare a pointer for strtod to inform us where it ended extracting the double from the string. */
   *retval = strtod( num, &endptr );  /* Run the extraction of the double from the source string (num) and give us the value so we can store it in the address given by the caller (retain the position in the string where strtod stopped processing). */
   if( endptr == NULL )
       return 0;  /* endptr should never be NULL, but it is a defensive programming to prevent dereferencing null in the next statement. */
   else if( *endptr != '\0 ) /* If we are pointing to a non-null character, then there was an invalid character that strtod did not accept and stopped processing.  So it is not only a double on the line.  So we reject. */
       return 0; /* Not strictly the double we are looking for. */ 
   /* else */
   return 1;  /* Return 1 to the caller to indicate truth (non-zero) that the value in *retval has valid double value to use. */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking, is there a way of just rejecting characters as `0.0` is a valid double. At the moment the string is converted to a double which gives `0.000` which is valid when it should not be

Comment: Explain your criteria more.  Are you saying that 0.0 is an invalid double?

Comment: Thanks for your answer and response. Basically, I want to store doubles such as `0.0` and not characters like `a` or `./a.out`. Problem is these characters are converted to double and produce `0.00000` and thus they become valid doubles. To summarize, I don't want to read any characters and store them. I want the program to instantly recognise them as characters and not valid scientific double or just double

Comment: Study the code example.  if( !endptr || ( *endptr != '\0' ) ) Reject(); else use( retval );

Comment: Could you please if you don't mind make the change to your code. I'm still not quite with you but I just want to reject characters or something that is not considered as a `double` or `scientific notation double`

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! :D, Can't thank you enough, but could you please explain this line, `return ( !endptr || ( *endptr != '\0' ) ) ? 0 : 1;` I don't get what is going on here, is there an easier way for a noob like me to understand

Comment: return 0 ==> FALSE if [(endptr is not null /* mainly defensive against dereferencing a null pointer in the next clause */ ) or ( endptr is not pointing to the end of the source line (the null terminator)) ) else return 1 ==> NOT 0 aka NOT FALSE aka TRUE

Comment: So if it is an invalid double it will not have `null terminator`? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Right.  If it is invalid double, strtod stops and leaves endptr pointing to the invalid character (the last unprocessed character).  If the last unprocessed character is null, then it reached the end of the string successfully.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it all :D. I have marked this as an `acceptable answer` although I wish I could have marked it as an `extraordinary answer` or `beneficial to any new C/C++ answer`. Nevertheless, thanks for your hard work and effort in helping me.